# Merge 2 water sources to a single output

Tags: plumbing

I have 2 water barrels (one on each side of the garage). I'm trying to join both outlets (male) into 1 outlet for use with the garden hose. That way I can draw from both sides. Is there a way to accomplish that without bulkheads and pvc work / joins?
Thank you

Edit: @isherwood: Completed solution (suggested by @crip659 & @Ecnerwal)[image]

Comment: Won't work with normal hoses, @crip659 - the splitter has one set of female threads and two sets of male threads.

Comment: I'm unclear about the problem. Hose connections are trivial. What challenge are you facing? Please revise to be more specific about your hardware, proximity, etc. Photos would be great.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  A knife and a few hose repair kits takes care of that problem.

Comment: Do both barrels have a hose bib as the drain source? Can you indeed hook a hose to these male outlets?   Or is the thread something other than hose thread?

Comment: Please post a photo of the barrels and the setup.  But I suspect it will be difficult without going across the garage at the floor level.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta: I'll connect the hose across on top of the driveway. This was meant to be manual watering needs utilizing both barrels equally and not automating watering functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick, crude, kludge; a splitter as mentioned by @crip659, but threaded onto one of the male hose ends, and a washing machine hose (2 female hose ends) joined to the other male hose end and one (normally output) side of the splitter. Your output hose to the other male hose end of the splitter.

Comment: @isherwood: I have 2 rain barrels - both outputs are male. I'm trying to combine / join both outputs to 1 single garden hose output. I'm trying to avoid PVC piping because I want to able to disconnect after use.  What crip659 and Ecnerwal suggested was using a 1 inlet (female) and 2 outlet (both male) Y garden splitter. Connect the splitter input (female) to one of the rain barrels male output. Use hose repair kits (female) or washing machine hose (female) to connect to one of the outputs on the splitter. Connect the garden hose to the other outputs of the splitter to garden hose like normal.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon appears to sell this device: [https://www.amazon.com/Washing-Machine-Fittings-Machines-Outdoor/dp/B0B6FXM79G](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B6FXM79G)

They list it for $15. But there are also "barb" y-fittings intended for 3/4" hose for much less. So, depending on your local big box hardware supplier, you might be able to beat the price, especially if you already have some junk hose ends laying about.